# Why is my __init__ not taking precedence in inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.5, overriding

I am trying to write a class that inherits from mmap as follows:

```
from mmap import mmap

class SBFMap(mmap):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        f=open(filename, 'rb')
        fn = f.fileno()
        super().__init__(fn, 0, access = mmap.ACCESS_READ)
```

As you can guess, part of my class's functionality is to hide the file opening/closing inside my __init__. i then try to get an SBFMap object like so:

```
from SBFMap import SBFMap
filename = "name\of\file"
mymap = SBFMap(filename)
```

I get this error:

```
File "SBFReader.py", line 22 in <module> main()
File "SBFReader.py", line 7, in main mymap=SBFMap(filename)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It appears like instead of python calling SBFMap's __init__ and letting me call mmap's __init__ when I'm ready to, python is trying to call mmap's __init__.  How do I fix this?

Comment: is this a typo? `f=open(filename, 'rb)`
Please copy/paste also the full stacktrace.

Comment: Two possible solutions: use delegation instead of inheritance. And for some classes, e.g. str or datetime, you can't overload __init__. I forgot the exact details, but you can try `__new__` instead.

Comment: @Markon Yes, that was a typo, which is now fixed. I also added the stack trace.

Comment: The error is indeed being raised by `SBFMap.__new__`. Note that `mmap` is implemented in a shared library in C, not pure Python, and it does not actually have an `__init__` method.

Comment: Read about [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are two different special methods that are involved in object creation: `__new__` that creates and object and `__init__` that configures it.

Generally Python mutable classes use a default `__new__` that ends calling `object.__new__` to create a new python object and accept any arguments.

But some classes (notably non mutable ones) do override `__new__`. In that case, you **must** implement one in your class and call the one from the parent class with the expected signature.

Once the object will be constructed, Python will eventually call the `__init__` method for the actual object.

Here you should do:

```
class SBFMap(mmap):
    def __new__(cls, filename):
        f=open(filename, 'rb')
        fn = f.fileno()
        return super().__new__(cls, fn, 0, access = mmap.ACCESS_READ)
```

But beware, if the parent class expected its `__init__` method to be called, you would still have to implement one in your class that calls the parent `__init__` with the expected signature.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  The __new__ method is a bit confusing at first.